# How to redirect a newly registered user to a custom URL after signing up?

Tags: 7, users, redirection, theming

By default after a new user signs up, a redirect to the home page happens.

But in such case I want to redirect such user to another page like node/35.

In this node/35 I then want to display some content.

Comment: If you can try any module then you can do this by using LoginToBoggan module which I have suggested in answer. You can also do this by using Rules module also do this by custom code mention in my answer.

Comment: I think you can easily do this by using LoginToBoggan module which I have mentioned & Rules module which @Pierre.Vriens mention in there answer. It's not a difficult task.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to do this.

Here is how such (fairly basic) rule would look like, based on your extra comment in my answer (= new users that register do NOT need admin approval):

- **Event**: After saving a new user account.
- **Condition**: None
- **Action**: Page redirect (with value = Node/35 in your case).

The above is just a basic rule. You might want to enhance it in various ways. E.g. add a 2nd action to the very same rule to just set a special welcome message (near the top of the main content of your pages).

Comment: there is any approval given from admin just sign up after redirect to custom page like node/35

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using [LoginToboggan](https://www.drupal.org/project/logintoboggan) module.

> The LoginToboggan module offers several modifications of the Drupal
>   login system in an external module by offering the many features
>   and usability improvements.

**OR**

```
<?php
function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state,$form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'user_register_form':
          $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_user_register_submit';
      break;
  }
}

function custom_user_register_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'node/add/business';
}
?>
```

Comment: thanks to answer to my question but in this code where i can provide can u tell me in briefly

Comment: What can I tell you briefly. I don't think so above code is not understandable. Simply `$form_state['redirect'] = 'node/35';`